# How to remove results from batch command

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am sort of new to coding, and tried looking around. My goal is to remotely obtain Domain Controller from a machine on the network. The command I am using via batch is below. I want to filter the results from nltest to only display the DC Name. I don't want connection status, and flags.

```
:Start
color 02
cls
@echo off
Echo.
Echo Domain Controller Finder
Echo.

Set /P Computer=Enter the Asset ID:
If  "%Computer%"==  "" goto BadName

nltest /sc_query:<Domain_Name> /server:%Computer%
pause

Goto End

:BadName
Cls
Echo.
Echo You have entered an incorrect name or left this field blank
Echo Please enter a valid Name or press Ctr-C to exit.
Echo.
Pause
Goto Start

:End
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the DC Name begins with `\\`, so you could try this:

```bat
@ECHO OFF

:Begin
SET/P "AssetID=Enter the Asset ID: "
IF "%AssetID%"=="" GOTO BadName

SET "DCName="
FOR /F "TOKENS=1* DELIMS=\" %%A IN (
    'nlest /sc_query:<Domain_Name> /server:%AssetID%^|FIND "\\"'
) DO SET "DCName=\\%%B"

IF DEFINED DCName (ECHO %%DCName%% = %DCName%
    PAUSE & GOTO End)

:BadName
```

Note. I changed `:Start` to `:Begin` because Start is a command and looks wrong, the decision is yours.